# StackOverFlow in Clojure even when I am using bigint

Tags: clojure, biginteger

I am using the below code to find the factorial.

```
(defn factorial [x]
  (if (< x 2)
    1N
    (*' (factorial (- x 1)) x)))
```

I am using the bigint operations `*'` and `-'` but even after that I am getting stackoverflow errors when I am calling it using 5500 and above.

```
StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.Numbers$LongOps.combine (Numbers.java:419)
user=> (factorial 5300)

StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.Numbers$LongOps.add (Numbers.java:455)
user=> (factorial 5300)
```

I have looked at other questions but they say that using these operations should give me correct answer. So what am I missing here?

I am learning Clojure so this is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StackOverflowError` occurs because `factorial` invokes itself recursively. Large numbers of `x` expand into too many nested `factorial` invocations, causing the stack to overflow.

You should rewrite your function to use [`loop`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc11)/[`recur`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc12) instead of recursive invocations:

```
(defn factorial [n]
  (loop [cnt n acc 1N]
     (if (zero? cnt)
        acc
        (recur (dec cnt) (*' acc cnt)))))
```